# A "modern" look of Manifest file

Tags: android, android-manifest

A "traditional" Manifest files consisted of `application/activities` tags, `uses-sdk` tag and `uses-persmission` eventually.

What are the new tags that you advise to include in the "modern" Manifest file? I am referring to the tags that deals with screens and resolutions, and possibly something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [look at the one from Barcode Scanner](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/AndroidManifest.xml), if that's a helpful data point. I don't think manifests are that different from what you describe. `<supports-screens>` is common now. `<compatible-screens>`, `<uses-configuration>`, and `<receiver>` pop up too. The complete docs [are here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).

Comment: Thanks. I was avoiding `<supports-screens>` and `<compatible-screens>` as my previous apps were intended for both mobiles and tablets, all screens and resolution. However, for the sake of future-proofing the app I will include these tags as well. Thanks also for mentioning the Google app as it is a great reference indeed. I usually use their apps for code style, but I forgot about it in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Some of attributes which we Android developers should normally include in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. Here it is:

Those common tags/attributes are:

- android:versionCode
- android:versionName
- android:icon
- android:label
- android:debuggable
- android:installLocation
- supports-screens
- uses-sdk
- uses-permission
- uses-library

Still, I know there are many other new tags/attributes. Those are:

[image]

Refer to *[The AndroidManifest.xml File](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)* for more information about the same:

Comment: Thanks for replying. It a great reply for new developers, but it a bit too broad for myself. I was expecting more specific suggestion like Sean's as I know what I can include, but I do not know what other developers usually include. I have you the upvote for your effort.